# Monitoring pod termination time with prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I'm looking for a Prometheus metric that would allow me to monitor the time pods spend in the `terminating` state before vanishing into the void.

I've tried playing around with `kube_pod_container_status_terminated` but it only seems to register pods once they finish the termination process, but don't help me understand how long does it take to terminate a pod.
I've also looked at `kube_pod_status_phase` which I found out about in this channel a while ago but it also seems to lack this insight.

I'm currently collecting metrics on my k8s workload using cAdvisor, kube-state-metrics and the prometheus node-exporter, but would happily considering additional collectors if they contain the desired data.
A non-prometheus solution would also be great.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What version of Kubernetes do you use? You can collect this timestamps from API server. but solution different for versions.

Comment: 1.8.8, I'm aware of the option of an API request which can be parsed and then written as a metric but I was really hoping I can just get this info our of the myriad of metrics exported to prometheus. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [pod-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/fad76e457a5cc0da10a6defed00539d256435c20/docs/pod-metrics.md#useful-metrics-queries) documentation:

> It is not straightforward to get the Pod states for certain cases like "**Terminating**" and "Unknown" since it is not stored behind a field in the Pod.Status.

> So to mimic the logic used by the `kubectl` command line, you will need to compose multiple metrics.
> [...]
>
> - **For Pods in Terminating state:** `count(kube_pod_deletion_timestamp) by (namespace, pod) * count(kube_pod_status_reason{reason="NodeLost"} == 0) by (namespace, pod)`

> Here is an example of a Prometheus rule that can be used to alert on a Pod that has been in the `Terminated` state for more than `5m`.

```
groups:
- name: Pod state
  rules:
  - alert: PodsBlockInTerminatingState
    expr: count(kube_pod_deletion_timestamp) by (namespace, pod) * count(kube_pod_status_reason{reason="NodeLost"} == 0) by (namespace, pod) > 0
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: page
    annotations:
      summary: Pod {{$labels.namespace}}/{{$labels.pod}} block in Terminating state.
```

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes itself, Heapster and metrics-server don't provide such metrics, but you can get metrics close to what you've mentioned by installing [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics). It has several pod metrics that reflect pods state:

```
kube_pod_status_phase
kube_pod_container_status_terminated
kube_pod_container_status_terminated_reason
kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason
```

You can find the full list of pods metrics, provided by `kube-state-metrics` in [Documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/Documentation/pod-metrics.md).

There is also [Bitnami Helm chart](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kube-state-metrics/) that could simplify the installation of `kube-state-metrics`.